# SQL select subquery within case when using MAX function

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use max function within case when query for my report, but I am receiving an error

> ORA-01427 - single row subquery returns more than one row

while creating subquery. I read about it and I tried to rearrange code but still doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to write it correctly please? I am kind of junior. Thank you!
This is part of the query

```
case when        
(
(select max_day from   
(select max(a.day) as max_day, 
a.id as id_customer
from table a  
group by a.id))
<= '30'

and a.c in ('A','B','C') 
and a.d not in ('1','2')
)
then a.amount

end as amount_30
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Simplify! [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You inner query return "max_day" for each "id", case must get one row. Put you select as query and join it

```
select case when b.max_day <= '30'
         and a.c in ('A','B','C') 
         and a.d not in ('1','2')  then a.amount end as amount_30
     from yourtable a join (select max(a.day) as max_day, 
     a.id as id_customer from table a  group by a.id) b
     on a.id=b.id_customer
```

Comment: Thank you Lev, it looks good but it says missing keyword in line 'where a.id=b.id_customer'. Don't you know why pls?

Comment: Try to replace "join" with "inner join" and  "where" with "on".

Comment: Yes, I replaced "where" with "on" and it's working and showed desired results. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**DAY**       248, 1, 0, 28
**ID**        1, 1, 2, 1
**AMOUNT**    2321, 4351, 4261, 325
**C**         A, A, C, C
**D**         1, 4, 5, 5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnIM5.png)

Condition is to choose max amount of days for each ID (max day on ID level), and then to use due amount. (also while following other conditions  <= '30', a.c in ('A','B','C'), a.d not in ('1','2')

From example above, expected result is amount 325 for ID = 1.